# Hapi + Boom - Which types I should assign to error?

Tags: hapi

I use hapi + boom, but I don't know which types I should add to error.
At the moment my code look likes:

```
  } catch (error: any) {
    return Boom.badImplementation(error.message);
  }
```

What types is error? And where I can found information about it?

Answer (score 0):

hello i don't know if this is still relevant
but you can see the doc here: https://hapi.dev/module/boom/api/?v=10.0.1#http-4xx-errors

When you say type, what exactly are you talking about?
if you ask what is the type of the argument of the function
then the type is a String

if not, I invite you to detail your request

I add the following answer maybe it will help you :

for the implementation of `Boom.notFound()` now you can call the function directly (with `HapiJs` anyway `@hapi/boom`)
you can do like this

```js
import { app } from '../../../server';
import { IpingController } from '../types/ping.type';
import { badRequest } from '@hapi/boom';

/**
 * controller ping
 */
export const PingController: IpingController = {
    /**
     * route ping pour tester le server et retourner une valeur
     * @param request
     * @param h
     * @param err
     * @return {status: number, message: string}
     */
    get: (request, h, err) => {
        if (err) {
            app.server.log('error', 'Une erreur est survenu');
            return badRequest(err);
        }

        app.server.log('log', 'pin OK');
        return { status: 200, message: 'pin OK' };
    }
};
```

badRequest() ou notFound() it's the same
the argument of its functions are a `String` or the `err` object